# Administration of bfgminer in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bfgminer

I'm just starting to screw around with bitcoin mining.  I've been a long time Boinc pseudo-enthusiast and so I just had to check out bitcoin mining.  I've started using bfgminer and I'm a little confused as to how its administration should go.

I get it running in the terminal and it shows me the main menu, but is there a way to exit out of that menu and keep it running in the background?  Then once it's going, is there a way to bring the menu back up to check in on it?

I've looked around for an answer to this and I haven't been able to find one yet; can anyone put me on the right track?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GNU Screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) is often the ideal tool to run interactive programs in the background. You can also run it with --syslog and/or --api-listen to have a more traditional daemon-type process.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply Luke!  Would I be correct in presuming that you're the manager of the bfgminer project?  If so, many thanks for the software!  I think I'm sort of getting the picture but say I wanted to get it running via ssh and then forget it would I run `bfgminer --api-listen`?  In that case, how might I be able to log back in to check how it's running?  Thanks again for the reply.

Comment: If you start BFGMiner outside a screen and without --api-listen, the only way to get into it remotely would be to attach GDB and manually start it - and that wouldn't be very simple.